# Right way to import ts files from an npm module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, import, microservices

There was a need to split a ts project into several repositories/packages, and from their various combinations to build microservices. Some packages are needed in one microservice, some in another, some in all.

At deploy the code is compiled and JS files are executed (of course).

But now it turns out that if a plug-in package simply exports some code from a ts file, then an error occurs during the execution of the compiled microservice, because the microservice code tries to import something from an external library and does not find a js file with such content.

And for the correct maintaining of such a system, I need not only to make changes to the ts code of the connected packages, but also to build them, push the compiled code into a repository and publish the npm package also including this compiled code.
It's inconveniently, it looks weird, and it's easy to forget.

Is there a way to organize repositories/npm packages in such a way that only TS code is published (and kept up-to-date), and when on a microservice compiling ts code is pulled from an external library and the JavaScript is generated once in one place during the deployment?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but we solved something very similar with lerna. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are many ways. I have come up with the next one for myself. Screwed github actions to automatically build and upload to npm when pushing to the master. I would have to modify that all this was happening only if the version has changed, but already sleepy (and so works because if the version has not changed then pablish error will fall, just pipeline long spin will be).

Here is the first version of a yaml file for the action:

```
name: npm-publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  npm-publish:
    name: npm-publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@master
      with:
        node-version: 12
        registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

    - name: Remove a dist folder from gitignore
      run: sed -i '$ d' .gitignore

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm i

    - name: Build
      run: npm run build

    - name: Publish
      run: npm publish
      env:
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: the actual result can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-react-views there is no js code in the repository, but if the package is installed in your project, everything is well connected in runtime